# postgresql database creation script

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Long time user of sql server, i'm migrating to postgresql.

In sql server, i was able to script the entire database (drop/create), table create (...) from a single file as the `GO` keyword is a batch separator.

In postgresql,

```sql
DROP DATABASE "appweb";

CREATE DATABASE "appweb"
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Result error `database drop cannot run inside a transaction block`

How i can do this in postgresql ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't start a transaction. Maybe your SQL client does this implicitly for you. Which tool do you use to run this?

Comment: i'm using pgadmin, just opening the file and execute. same error when disabling the autocommit setting in the toolbar button

Comment: You need to **enable** autocommit

Comment: when adding "SET AUTOCOMMIT ON" in the head of script, i get an error

Comment: You need to enable autocommit in pgAdmin

Comment: autocommit is the default setting in pgAdmin and do not work

Comment: Would this not work from the CLI as a script ?

Comment: @BufferUnderRun: I don't use pgAdmin, but I would expect that if autocommit is enabled, this error shouldn't happen. Do you maybe have an explicit `begin transaction` in your script that you are not showing us? What happens if you run each statement on its own?

Comment: I can confirm that with `Auto Commit` on and more then one statement in the Query Tool a transaction will be opened. The only I could get `DROP DATABASE` to work was to run it in the Query Tool by itself. This is a `pgAdmin4` issue not a Postgres one as doing `DROP DATABASE ...; CREATE DATABASE ...;` works in `psql`.